# New GiT project - Where is the project history?

Tags: git

Using GiT I created an empty folder, opened a GiT bash at that location and entered

> git init

I see that GiT creates a hidden .git dir like other VCs do.
Then I created file readme.txt and added it:

> git add readme.txt -m "adding readme.txt"

Then I thought - "where am I committing my changes to? I haven't designated a local repo or a remote one. This is very disorienting. Can I keep making changes and work locally without ever creating a distributed repository? Or, have I just created that repository locally and each instance of it is a clone of it?

Comment: "I haven't designated a local repo" Yes you have. `git init` makes a local repo for you, all located in a hidden `.git` folder where you ran the `git init` command.

Comment: After several minutes went by I noticed that the icon overlays appear on the readme file. This would have been my visual cue that things were happening locally when using other VC tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to create a distributed repository. Git is cool like that. It's very flexible.  Later on, when you are ready, you can push the changes in this repository to a remote repository.  Feel free to work locally for now.

[Use the Git-SCM documentation to get you started.](http://git-scm.com/doc)  It is what helped me immensely when learning this technology.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out what branch your on with "git status" you can bring up a GUI of your git history with "gitk".

"git add" doesn't commit anything it just stages it.

To commit you use "git commit"

"Can I keep making changes and work locally without ever creating a distributed repository?" - YES